How can I update a column whenever something in the row is updated?
I currently have a column called LAST_UPDATED_ON . Normally when I update something in the query I add to the query the LAST_UPDATED_ON so something like this:
UPDATE TABLE
SET 
    COLUMN = :COLUMN,
        LAST_UPDATED_ON = NOW()
WHERE ID = :ID

I'm using SQL with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
My question is:
Is there anyway that I could update the column whenever I updated the row without passing it?
Clarification:
I want to be able to write update table set somecolumn = somevalue and have LAST_UPDATED_ON to be automatically updated to GETDATE().
What I have works, but I'm trying to improve my code day to day.
Current Configuration

What do you mean update the parameter whenever you update the row? As in assign the value of the current data and time to a 2nd parameter, or the value assigned to the table? Have you had a look at the OUTPUT clause?

@ThomA what I mean with update is that if I update any part of that row, the last_updated_on param gets updated. Hope this clarifies what I mean. I'll check now what OUTPUT does.

I think he wants to be able to write just update table set somecolumn = somevalue and have LAST_UPDATED_ON to be automatically updated to GETDATE(). This is not possible without triggers and that is usually a bad idea. You could write a procedure that did the updating, because i hope you're not using the GUI to update data

You would have to use a TRIGGER to UPDATE the row, if you want any and all UPDATE statements to change the value of the column (without explicitly setting it). Alternatively, if you also want to keep the history of the table, you could use a temporal table.

Also, LAST_UPDATED_ON is not a "parameter", it is a column. A parameter is something entirely different, hence the confusion here.

@ThomA I made a trigger and it actually worked. Whenever I make an update in any column the LAST_UPDATED_ON column gets updated. Also, sorry for using "parameter", I'm getting to know how to properly speak in SQL language haha

There are some caveats, but you can do this without triggers using temporal table functionality.
